# How to mask all PII columns of all tables in a specific schema based on datatype of columns in Snowflake using python?

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Use case-I want to apply different masking policies based on datatype of columns.e.g if column has a datatype of name then I want to apply mask_name policy and if datatype is string then mask_string.How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Data Masking policies are applied on specific columns (not on all table), so you can create different policies and apply them as you want. Same policy can be applied to multiple columns. Based on your use-case, you can create a policy such as mask_string, and apply it to varchar columns:

```
create or replace masking policy mask_string as (val string) returns string ->
  case
    when current_role() in ('ANALYST') then val
    else '*********'
  end;


alter table user_info modify column first_name set masking policy mask_string;

alter table user_info modify column last_name set masking policy mask_string;
```

More information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-column-ddm-use.html#using-dynamic-data-masking

Comment: Yes I want to apply different masking policies based on datatype of columns using python.i have created different masking policies but I am not getting a way to implement logic in python code to first check data type of column and then apply masking policy

Comment: From information schema,columns I can get the table and column names that are present in specific schema and can assign the result to a list but how do I implement logic to first check data type of columns present in a schema and apply masking policy

Comment: So you are asking us to write a python script to automate this process. The initial question is not clear about it. It's not a big deal to write such a simple script from scratch but it would be better if you share your script and ask us to fix the issues you encountered.

Comment: I am not asking you to write a python script.I think you didn't get the context.I just wanted help on how do I apply masking policy based on data type of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the steps
Steps 1: Create multiple Masking policies as per your business requirement. Even though it is one time requirement but you have to revisit if business rule changes.

Step 2: Create a python program. Assign variables for each policy. Run loop for each data type and create Alter statement and assign it to a variable. Execute it in the Program or create a consolidated file for all alter statements and execute the file using SnowSQL.